# Need to add state value in useEffect to see non initial value in functions

Tags: reactjs

So, react is show me the initial/old state.

I have this code

```
const Users = () => {
    const { rightSideBarState, setRightSideBarState } = React.useContext(RightSidebarContext);
    const { setHeaderState } = React.useContext(HeaderContext);
    const [active, setActive] = React.useState<string | null>(null);
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = React.useState<string>('');
    const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState<User.UserData[]>([]);

    console.log('user Data:', userData);

    const onAddingNewUser = async (services: User.SucessfulInvitationSent[], email: string) => {
        console.log('EmaiL:', email, userData);
    };

    const { refetch } =
        useQuery([`users`], () => getUsersData(searchText).then((data) => setUserData(data)), {
            suspense: true,
        }) ?? [];

    const onAddUserClicked = () => {
        setRightSideBarState({
            visible: true,
            rightSidebarDisplay: {
                headerTitle: 'Add Users',
                headerCloseAction: () => {
                    setRightSideBarState({ visible: false });
                    setActive('');
                },
                content: <RightSidebarCreateUser onAddingNewUser={onAddingNewUser} />,
            },
        });
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setHeaderState({
            rightContent: (
                <HeaderRightController
                    searchText={searchText}
                    setSearchText={(val) => {
                        setSearchText(val);
                    }}
                    onClickAddUser={onAddUserClicked}
                />
            ),
            path: PATHS.USERS,
        });
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [searchText]);
```

Here, in useEffect if I don't add `userData` then the state passed is always the initial value, but If I do add, the state passed is always the updated one.

Can someone please help me in understanding why this could be happening.

To add bit more context.

I have components, like these

```
const Header = ({ leftContent, rightContent, path }: Props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const [headerInfo, setHeaderInfo] = React.useState(getHeaderInfo());
  const [overwriteHeader, setOverWriteHeader] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof path === 'object') {
      setHeaderInfo(path);
    } else {
      setHeaderInfo(getHeaderInfo);
    }
    const actualPath = window.location.pathname;

    if (actualPath !== path) {
      setOverWriteHeader(true);
    } else {
      setOverWriteHeader(false);
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [location, path]);
  return (
    <PaneHeader
      closeable={false}
      heading={headerInfo.title}
      icon={headerInfo.iconName as IconName}
      subtabs={leftContent ? leftContent : null}
      actions={
        <Stack direction="row" align="center">
          {!overwriteHeader && rightContent && <Box>{rightContent} </Box>}
        </Stack>
      }
    />
  );
};
```

Which exists on route level

```
  const { headerState } = React.useContext(HeaderContext);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Header {...headerState} />
           <Routes>
            ....
          </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
   )
```